# SQL Inner Join and filtering out results

Tags: sql, database

I'm doing a query for a report, and I need help with the INNER JOINs I've been trying to make work for weeks. Its apart of a larger report query, but I need help in this final part taht is supposed to filter certain results.

Each row in `cwo_work_order_line_item` represents a item on a certain work order grouped together by transaction sequences. This query is joining this and another table for a report, `cat_cust_item_acct_activity`. That table shows different transactions dealing with a certain account.

This certain section of the report is supposed to only show items that are charged as 'Estimate.' This query works perfectly fine until an item gets changed to an actual price on a different transaction than when it was set up.

The problem is that the table `cwo_work_order_line_item` gets a new item inserted into it with a different transaction sequence (trans_seq column) and `cat_cust_item_acct_activity` gets a new item as well. This happens instead of actually modifying the original row representing the item ean each table.

What this means is that the report is still showing the original item (the setup item) on the report even after the price was changed from Estimate to Actual.

Here's a pic of the two tables in my database. Seeing this will help me better explain the problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVlQY.png

In the example in the picture, the first table is `cwo_work_order_line_item`. the trans_seq 1052833 is the tranasction when the items were set up. The query is only checking if these items are set to a price of 'ACTUAL' and not 'ESTIMATE', which is represented in price_status_enum column.

The 3rd row shows a different transaction, 1052834, where the customer changed the item price to an actual price, hence "ACTUAL."

In the second table, `cat_cust_item_acct_activity`, you can see the actions completed by the customer. The only thing that seemingly connects the items from the first and second table is `rtrans_lineitm_seq` from the first table, and `cust_item_acct_detail_item_nbr` in the second.

So this is what I think I need to do:
I need to make this query to check the second table to see if there is a 'MODIFY_PRICE' in `item_acct_activity_code` and then retrieve that row's `cust_item_acct_detail_item_nbr`. Then make sure that the row in the first table is not joined where the `cust_item_acct_detail_item_nbr` is equal to the `rtrans_lineitm_seq` in the first table

Original Query:
This query works if the price_status_enum is not changed or changed in the same transaction when it is set up.

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT(ca.cust_acct_id)                 
FROM
   cwo_work_order_acct ca              
INNER JOIN
   cat_cust_item_acct_activity acty                
      ON                      ca.organization_id = acty.organization_id                     
      AND ca.cust_acct_id = acty.cust_acct_id                     
      AND ca.cust_acct_code = acty.cust_acct_code              
INNER JOIN
   cwo_work_order_line_item cli                         
      ON                          acty.organization_id = cli.organization_id                         
      AND acty.wkstn_id = cli.wkstn_id                         
      AND acty.trans_seq = cli.trans_seq                         
      AND acty.business_date = cli.business_date                         
      AND acty.rtl_loc_id = cli.rtl_loc_id                         
      AND acty.rtrans_lineitm_seq = cli.rtrans_lineitm_seq              
      AND cli.price_status_enum ='ESTIMATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a sub select in order to get the most recent sequence number, like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ca.cust_acct_id)                 
FROM cwo_work_order_acct ca              
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT 
    act.organization_id,
    act.wkstn_id,
    act.business_date,
    act.rtl_loc_id,
    act.rtrans_lineitm_seq,
    max(act.trans_seq) trans_seq --Get the most recent seq number
  FROM cat_cust_item_acct_activity act                
  GROUP BY
        act.organization_id,
        act.wkstn_id,
        act.business_date,
        act.rtl_loc_id,
        act.rtrans_lineitm_seq        
  ) as acty
  ON  ca.organization_id = acty.organization_id                     
  AND ca.cust_acct_id = acty.cust_acct_id                     
  AND ca.cust_acct_code = acty.cust_acct_code

INNER JOIN cwo_work_order_line_item cli                         
  ON  acty.organization_id = cli.organization_id                         
  AND acty.wkstn_id = cli.wkstn_id                         
  AND acty.trans_seq = cli.trans_seq                         
  AND acty.business_date = cli.business_date                         
  AND acty.rtl_loc_id = cli.rtl_loc_id                         
  AND acty.rtrans_lineitm_seq = cli.rtrans_lineitm_seq              
  AND cli.price_status_enum ='ESTIMATE'
```